# What is the correct way to calculate the accuracy for multiple classes in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to use Keras to evaluate the performance of a machine learning model on a multi-class problem. The ground truths and the predictions by the models are in labels. While it is fairly easy to create the instance from `keras.metrics.Accuracy`, and use the instance to calculate the accuracy, there seems to be another definition to the accuracy.
I feel confused about the definitions.

Say there are five classes labelled as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and there are four samples.
The ground truth labels are `yt = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]`,
and the predictions are `yp = [[0], [2], [3], [4]]`.
Then it is straightforward to have the following code to calculate the accuracy:

```
m = keras.metrics.Accuracy()
accuracy = m(yt, yp).numpy()
```

which gives 0.75 because there are 3 out of 4 samples classified correctly.

However, there are also literatures (e.g., Data Science written by Vijay Kotu and Bala Deshpande) give a different definition, where accuracy is defined by (TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FP + FN), and TP, TN, FP, FN are true positives, true negatives, false positives, and false negatives.
More specifically, if we have k classes, TP = TP_1 + TP_2 + ... + TP_k, and the same applies for TN, FP, FN.

To calculate TP, TN, FP, FN,
I first convert the labels into onehot vectors:

```
yt = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

yp = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Then the accuracy can be calculated by the following code:

```
m11 = keras.metrics.TruePositives()
m00 = keras.metrics.TrueNegatives()
m01 = keras.metrics.FalsePositives()
m10 = keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()

TP = m11(yt, yp).numpy()
TN = m00(yt, yp).numpy()
FP = m01(yt, yp).numpy()
FN = m10(yt, yp).numpy()

accuracy = (TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FP + FN)
```

which gives 0.9 because there are 3 TPs, 15 TNs out of all 20 combinations.

At first glance, it seems that the two definitions produce different accuracies.
However, if I calculate the recall rate using the TP and the FN above
(recall rate = TP / (TP + FN)), it will give 0.75, exactly the same value as
the first definition of accuracy!

If I treat correct predictions as TP, and incorrect predictions as FN,
it is easy to see that it has the same form as the recall rate.
So is the first definition actually the recall rate,
or the latter definition cannot be applied in onehot vectors?

Answer (score 1):

In multi-class classification accuracy refers to the `keras.metrics.Accuracy()` implementation that is `number_of_correct_predictions/number_of_predictions`. The definition with TP, TN, FP, FN only holds for binary classification. Complete details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision#In_classification

If you want to extend the TP/N, FP/N definition for n classes, the accuracy of a predictor that is systematically wrong should be (n-2)/n = 1-2/n because 1 FP, 1 FN and n-2 TN per prediction. That sounds particularly strange as it is close to 1 especially for big n.

The recall rate is another metric for binary classification (at least under the definition `TP/(TP+FN)`) used where we are particularly interested in well predicting all samples of class 1. In general it is different from accuracy. For instance if the model predicts always 1, the recall is 1 but the accuracy can be 0.5 (if 50% 1 and 50% 0).

Therefore your first definition is not the recall but the accuracy in binary classification only.

Comment: Is it valid to extend the recall rate into multi-class? For example, for m correct predictions out of n samples, there are m TPs and n-m FNs which produces recall rate of m/n, the same value as multi-class accuracy. It is only possible to have different values under multi-label problems.

Comment: You can compute all "one-vs-all" recall rate if you want as you transform the multi-label problem to multiple binary problems